# What are the best(for me) SSDs to install in Dell G5 5590?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I'm going to buy a laptop and by now that Dell seems a good choice to me. Reading the manual,they let me in a doubt about which SSDs I need to buy when I upgrade it.

Please, I'll install the two types available: M.2 and SATA 3. So,a tip for each of these would be better.

The best options for storage are:

> **M.2 slot**
>
> - Form factor: *One M.2 2280 solid-state driver*
> - Interface type: *PCIe NVMe 3x4 [Class 40](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1529476-what-is-the-difference-among-class-10-class-20-and-class-40-ssds)*
> - Capacity: *Up to 1TB*
>
>   ---
>
> **SATA 3 slot**
>
> - Form factor: *One 2.5" HDD*
> - Interface type: *SATA(of course)*
> - Capacity: *2TB(5400 RPM)*

***I'll install two or even three different Linux distros in SATA's SSD so I need to know the best options for this specific usage, I'm doing some research about it yet so I may add important information later.***

**ADVICE**: I don't like HDDs so I will replace it soon. I'd like and it's better to install less storage SATA's SSD instead 2TB HDD. Unfortunately [manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/g-series-15-5590-laptop_service-manual_en-us.pdf) do not shows SSDs options for SATA. I have no idea what are the relationships between RPM and SSD's speed.

Comment: That laptop supports M.2 2280 and 2230 form factors and has support for NVMe. I can not determine whether the M.2 port supports SATA mode but it probably does. You should add this information to your question instead of posting a screenshot. Screenshots are not search engine friendly!

Comment: "the best" is a rather arbitrary term to search for SSDs. Highest sequential throughput? Highest random throughput? Highest write endurance? Lowest latency? Better explain what types of applications you need it for, and if there is a budget constraint.

Comment: What's your budget? How much storage do you want/need?

Comment: @JMY1000 my budget is unlimited for this case. 1TB for M.2 and,if possible, at least 1TB for SATA. I'll need to add some information about the relationship between speed and storage in SATA slots for SSDs. For a while I don't get it yet.

Comment: @J-Mello Unlimited, as in you want the best you can get (within reason), or as in you don't have a specific cap but want to optimize for value?

Comment: @JMY1000 So, I don't have a specific cap but I want to optimize for value. For the specs (1TB for M.2 class 4 and at least 1TB for SATA) I think the maximum price is $350 for each SSD type.I've talked with Dell's employee and he said me that SATA slot supports up to 512GB for SSDs but I don't believe him cause I guess he gave me a wrong information about M.2 slot. Of course,cost benefit buying such hardwares is good.

Comment: @J-Mello No idea where he's getting those numbers. I'm going to assume no such limitations.

Answer (score 1):

## NVMe drive: ADATA SX8200 or HP EX950 (ideally on better sale)

**(unless you're a student in which case WD all the things)**

Since we're targeting the high end but still want reasonable, we probably want a nice TLC drive, and can afford to drop a some money on a good controller—especially since we're looking at a relatively high capacity boot drive. So, for now, we'll keep ourselves restricted to [SMI SM2262/SM2262EN](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13759/comparing-adata-sx8200-pro-vs-hp-ex950), Samsung, and WD based drives. If you want a Phison E12 controller would probably do just fine, but hey, we've got a little budget. Basically, we're targeting the high end of the midrange value/performance desktop options.

At this point, it's largely just a value contest based on who's on a slightly better sale so we can extract the best value. The following is arranged in an order of generally increasing performance/price:

- [Mushkin Pilot-E](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/JHxbt6/mushkin-pilot-e-1-tb-m2-2280-nvme-solid-state-drive-mknssdpe1tb-d8): Previously as low as $130, but currently at $150. Slower sibling the Pilot doesn't seem to be on sale anymore, and is thus not recommended.
- [ADATA SX8200 Pro](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/zR3H99/adata-sx8200-1-tb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-asx8200pnp-1tt-c)/[S11 Pro](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/qBCD4D/adata-xpg-gammix-s11-pro-1-tb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-agammixs11p-1tt-c): Has previously gone as low as $105, but is currently at $150. Slower sibling the SX8200 non-Pro/S11 (SMI SM2262) hasn't seen too many great sales.
- [HP EX950](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/PyhKHx/hp-ex950-1-tb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-5ms23aaabc): Was at around $125 throughout December, but is now back up to $140. It's slightly slower brethren, the EX900 and EX920, have seen some sales if you want to step down a tier or two.
- Kingston KC2000: Has never been price competitive. Not recommending.
- [Intel 760p](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/KVfhP6/intel-760p-series-1tb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-ssdpekkw010t8x1): Hasn't seen much in the way of sales. Was briefly at $160 but is currently at $200. Not recommending.
- [WD SN750](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/QQrmP6/western-digital-sn750-1-tb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-wds100t3x0c): Was down at $130 between December and January, but is back up to its normal price of $150. However, Western Digital does offer a 15% student discount, which, if you're eligible, makes it extremely price competitive.
- [Samsung 970 EVO](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/JLdxFT/samsung-970-evo-10tb-m2-2280-solid-state-drive-mz-v7e1t0baw): Currently sitting at $170. Has seen (rarely) as low as $135, but not super great value at this price point.

## 2.5" SATA drive: WD Blue, Team T-Force Vulcan, or Samsung 860 EVO (ideally on better sale)

Since you said you want to install OSs to this drive, not just use it as storage, we'll forego a more budget-oriented setup with the fast NVMe drive as a cache and this as more mass-storage in favor of a faster SSD. This time, we'll be looking at the Marvell 88SS1074, SMI SM2258/SM2259, and Samsung.

- [SanDisk Ultra 3D](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/FLDJ7P/sandisk-ultra-3d-1tb-25-solid-state-drive-sdssdh3-1t00-g25): Has previously hit $100, currently at pretty stable at $110.
- [WD Blue](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/GTCD4D/western-digital-blue-1tb-25-solid-state-drive-wds100t2b0a): Has previously hit $80, currently $110. Again, student discount could make the difference here.
- [Crucial MX500](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/h3tQzy/crucial-mx500-1tb-25-solid-state-drive-ct1000mx500ssd1): $105 right now, has seen as low as $90.
- [Lexar NS200](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/tQXnTW/lexar-ns200-960-gb-25-solid-state-drive-lns200-960rbna): Previously hit $80 with Google Express coupon, but otherwise, has maintained its price of $100.
- [Team T-Force Vulcan](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/q6ndnQ/team-t-force-vulcan-1-tb-25-solid-state-drive-t253tv001t3c301): Previously hit $85, currently at $110.
- Intel 545s: 1TB version no longer readily available, not recommending.
- Kingston KC600: No longer readily available, not recommending.
- [Samsung 860 EVO](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/yzfhP6/samsung-860-evo-1tb-25-solid-state-drive-mz-76e1t0bam): Has previously hit $100, but is currently at $150.